# C++ Namespace Declaration and Definition

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files

Folks,

I crated a name space in a single file, but how exactly do I separate the definition and declaration? 
Can I create a .h for declaration and a .cpp for definition just like in a class set of file? If yes, then, do I need to include the namespace header file in my new program, or is the using namspace mynamespace enough?

Comment: Yes, you can create a .h for declaration and a .cpp for definition. Just add the namespace to both files

Comment: Time to First Crate: two words.

Comment: If you plan on sticking `using mynamespace;` everywhere then all the names will end up in the global namespace, so don't bother with the namespace -- just put the names in the global namespace to begin with.

Comment: what do I do to use it? Do I include the myfile.h in my project, or do I go ahead and call using namespace myns right away? Also, I am planning on using the myns:: signature. That is the reason why I creating a namesapce

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any decent C++ book should cover namespaces and code separation.

Try something like this:

myfile.h

```
#ifndef myfile_H
#define myfile_H

namespace myns
{
    class myclass
    {
    public:
        void doSomething();
    };
}

#endif
```

myfile.cpp:

```
#include "myfile.h"

void myns::myclass::doSomething()
{
    //...
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
#include "myfile.h"

myns::myclass c;
c.doSomething();
```

Or:

```
#include "myfile.h"

using namespace myns;

myclass c;
c.doSomething();
```

Comment: what do I do to use it? Do I include the myfile.h in my project, or do I go ahead and call using namspace myns right away?

Comment: In cpp file, for definition of `doSomething()` instead of `void myns::myclass::doSomething()`, is `using myns;` ... `myclass::doSomething(){...}` valid? msvc as of Visual Studio 17.7.2 compiles it without issues. I'm using a C++20 module though, so perhaps that is why it compiles without error? Thank You